# Fitting component group set to bike

Tags: cassette, shifter

I received a Trek One Series 1.2 Alpha 100 and want to replace its components completely. I am trying to make sure I order the correct parts and sizes. How and what do I look for when buying new parts to make sure they correspond correctly.

Comment: Wanting to switch to Shimano 105

Comment: While searching for the specs, a couple of reviews commented that the brakes and tyres were the biggest problems with this bike.  If you want to spend as little as possible, start by replacing the brake pads and the tyres only.    Uprating the brake calipers may not be required if the pads are better.  We generally don't make brand recommendations, but Kool Stop really can't be beaten, plus this is a cheap upgrade.

Comment: Well, there is also SwissStop ;)

Answer (score 2):

As you mention upgrading to 105 I assume you are looking to upgrade the groupset only. If you want to upgrade wheels and other things as well you'd probably be better off selling the bike and buying a new one with the components you want.

Bicycle groupset components are extensively standardized so there are only a few things you need to know to ensure compatibility. On a rim-brake road bike it's even simpler that more modern hydraulic disc brake bikes. Basically you can just order a 105 version of each groupset component you have now. Shimano helpfully provides extensive documentation, the easiest way to look at the various options in a grouset and to see which components are compatible which each other is to look at the Line-Up pages. [Here's the one for the latest 105](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/lc/105_r7000/2x11).

However, there is a issue with upgrading to 11 speed 105. I'm assuming [this](https://www.bikeradar.com/reviews/bikes/road-bikes/trek-1-2-review/) is the bike that is equipped with a 9 speed Sora groupset. The rear wheel likely has a 10 speed and below compatible hub rather than a 11 speed compatible hub. The splined freehub body that the cassette slides onto is 1.85mm wider on an 11 speed hub. If your current cassette has a ~1.85mm spacer behind it you have a 11 speed hub.

If you don't have aa 11 speed hub you have a couple of choices: go for 10 speed Tiagra, buy a new rear wheel or make a 11 speed system work on a 10 speed hub. Some 11 speed cassettes will fit on a 10/9/8 speed hub, but they are all wider range ones with large inner sprockets. The Shimano 105 GS long cage derailleur will accommodate an 11-34 cassette (officially, many people say it will work with a 11-36). I'm not sure which 11 speed Shimano cassettes fit on a 10 speed hub so you are going this route you'll need to do some extra research.

If your bike has an FSA crank the bottom bracket will need to be updated along with the crank. If you have a '2-piece' Sora crank with the axle attached to the drive side crank and external bottom bracket cups threaded into the frame the 105 crank will fit in the bottom bracket cups, although of course you may choose to upgrade the bottom bracket anyway. I'm not sure if older Sora cranks had a '3-piece' type with a cassette type bottom bracket, if you have one of these you'll need to upgrade to 105 external bottom bracket cups.

For the Trek One Series you need rim brakes obviously, you want the 'dual pivot' style *not* direct mount. You'll need to determine if you need a 'band clamp' front derailleur that clamps on the seat tube or 'braze-on' that attaches to a lug on the seat tube (these lugs were brazed on on steel bike frames, hence the name).

The other choices are crank ring sizes and cassette range. If you are a beginner you'll probably want a lower range 'compact' 50/34 crank. If you live where there are hills you'll want a wider range cassette and long cage GS derailleur.

If you are installing all the components yourself there are great resources online for learning how to wrench on a bike. [Park Tool](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help) is the best IMHO. Also, Many online bike retailers offer groupset kits that include everything you need for an upgrade, that are cheaper than buying all the parts individually.

Comment: crikey its like we're copying each other....

Comment: @Criggie great minds think alike! I was wondering if someone else was typing up a response as I was composing mine.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by finding out what you have to work with.  Googling up "Trek One Series 1.2 Alpha 100 specs" returns these results

---

https://www.bikeradar.com/reviews/bikes/road-bikes/trek-1-2-review/ from 2016

- Bottom Bracket   FSA 68mm threaded, square taper
- Brake Levers Shimano Sora STI

---

https://www.trekbikes.com/international/en_IN_TL/bikes/road-bikes/performance-road-bikes/1-series/1-2/p/15807/

- Shimano Sora, 9-speed
- Derailleurs  - Shimano Sora
- Crank - FSA Vero 50/34 (compact)
- Bottom bracket - Sealed Cartridge
- Cassette - Shimano HG400, 11-28, 9-speed
- Chain - KMC X9
- Pedals - Wellgo nylon body w/alloy cage, toe-clip/strap

Components

- Saddle - Bontrager Paradigm 1
- Seatpost - Bontrager alloy, 2-bolt head, 27.2mm, 8mm offset
- Handlebar - Bontrager Race, VR-C, 31.8mm
- Grips - Bontrager gel cork tape
- Stem - Bontrager Elite, 31.8mm, 7-degree, w/Blendr computer & light mounts
- Head set  - 1-1/8" semi-cartridge bearings
- Brake set    - **unbranded** Alloy dual-pivot

---

This will work out quite expensive, so you might need to compare the upgrade costs with those for replacing the whole bike.  At least that way you will have a warranty and either a spare bike or one to sell on.

Shimano 105 is now an 11 speed groupset, so you're going to need to replace a lot.

One review noted that the wheels are quite decent, so don't replace them if yo udon't have to.  Depends whether they take an 11 speed cassette or not.

- Shifters, left and right
- Cassette, 11 speed, with whatever big cog you choose
- Rear derailleur, with a short or medium cage, depending on your cassette.
- 11 speed chain - its slightly narrower than your existing.
- Brake calipers
- Brake pads  (Just get kool stop ones - store the shimano default for spares)

Maybe replace:

- Front derailleur
- Cranks
- Bottom Bracket shell

It may be possible to keep the crankset as-is, or you may have to change to a new crankset and bottom bracket as well.  Depends how well the new left shifter operates the front derailleur

At this point you may as well recable the bike too, so add a pair of brake and a pair of gear inners and outers.   Consider replacing the pedals too, the "nylon body wellgo" is going to be dreadful.

---

Costs - take these with salt, but right now in April 20202 a Shimano R7000 groupset is 450 euro or 388 UKP.   Or you could look at the Tiagra 4700 10 speed groupset for about 300 UKP, which might be required if your rear wheel is limited to 10 speed.

You will need a bottom bracket shell and cables, and should consider pedals.

So think of the tools and labour you'll need to add to complete this, and estimate the value of a warranty.  Then shop for new bikes with the same spec and see how they stack up.  Remember you might keep the Trek as a second bike, give it away to family, or even sell it to recoup some costs of the new bike.  Its all up to you.

Comment: With the groupset and the tools it will be an expensive operation and you'll end up with a Sora-ready frame (meaning the mid-lower end of the spectrum) equipped with higher spec components that would beg for a higher spec frame, especially in matters of build quality and lower weight.